# SQL JOIN on 3 tables with multiple one-to-many

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I'm strugglinbg with an SQL query for quit some time now.
Here is what I'd like to accomplish :

Let's say we have 3 Tables : fruit, farmers & sales

These Tables are structured and filled as followed.

Fruits :

```
__|_fruit______|_taste_
 1| apple      | sweet
 2| banana     | sweet
 3| grapefruit | sour
```

Farmers :

```
__|_farmer___|_field_____
 1| ben      | apple
 2| mary     | banana
 3| mike     | grapefruit
 4| joanna   | apple
 5| clara    | grapefruit
```

Sales :

```
__|_fruit______|_amount__
 1| apple      | 50
 2| banana     | 25
 3| apple      | 30
 4| grapefruit | 40
 5| banana     | 45
 6| apple      | 30
```

I'd now like to be able to look which and how many of these fruit have been sold. A result, I could work with, would look something like this
(WHERE fruits.fruit = "apple") :

```
fruits.fruit | farmers.farmer | sales.amount
apple        | ben            | 50
apple        | joanna         | 30
apple        | null           | 30
```

or like this
(WHERE fruits.fruit = "banana") :

```
fruits.fruit | farmers.farmer | sales.amount
banana       | mary           | 25
banana       | null           | 45
```

or like this
(WHERE fruits.fruit = "grapefruit") :

```
fruits.fruit | farmers.farmer | sales.amount
grapefruit   | mike           | 40
grapefruit   | clara          | null
```

I'd store these results in php and could later determine, which farmer has to be paid what amount of money, because the farmers should be paid appropriate, regarding to the sold amount.

I'd like to do this with only one SQL query and without a cross reference table.
My approach to the problem was the following (which did greatly fail) :

```
SELECT fruits.fruit, farmers.farmer, sales.amount
FROM fruits
JOIN farmers ON farmers.field = fruits.fruit
JOIN sales ON sales.fruit = fruits.fruit
WHERE fruits.fruit = "apple"
```

The queries last line has to change, in order to get the previously shown results.

Is it reasonable to do this without a crossreference table?
Is it possible to do it?
Is there a completely different approach which would to be preferred here?

Thanks in advance

EDIT#1 : added a missing entry in sales (6)
EDIT#2 : MySQL - Version is 5.7.17

Comment: How can you deduce from your tables that there was 45 banana sold to a null farmer?  The sales should be linked to a farmer, no?

Comment: Also, cannot you put a field_fruit_id instead of a string for the field of the farmer?  Way better for normalization of data.

Comment: @MichaelMuryn they have not been sold to a null famer, the farmer sell relationship, is about the farmer who worked on the sold fruit. And for my pourpose I need the string. The example above is fictitious but relatable.

Comment: And I was missing an entry in sales, thanks for the hint

Comment: Please update your question if you were missing an entry on sales.  As I fail to see how you can get the null result without knowing what is missing. ;-)

Comment: How is it decided which farmer sold which quantity of which fruit? I don't see and references from table to table.

Comment: All fruits are sold in one spot. The farmers bring their fruits to this spot. If only apple have been sold later, only the farmers who delivered apples get payed. Thats the idea. The actual quantity doesn't matte for me. All farmers who worked on a certain fruit will get paid evenly

Comment: What is the version of mysql?

Comment: But you have no link between your Farmers and Sales table... how can you link the amount sold??

Comment: @MichaelMuryn I know on what fruit the farmers have worked and i know which fruit has been sold. Therefore I can link the farmers to the sales by the kind of fruit. If I'm understanding your question right.

Comment: @McRaef In your result example, you say that ben sold 50 apples, joanna 30 apples, and null (no farmer) has sold 30 apples.  How can you link these?  From the data I see, you cannot.

Comment: fruits.fruit = farmer.fruit && fruits fruit = sales.fruit  Can't I link them that way? Maybe with OUTER JOIN(which always returned a sql error for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `group by`:

```
SELECT fr.fruit, fa.farmer, sum(s.amount)
FROM sales JOIN
     fruits fr
     s.fruit = fr.fruit LEFT JOIN
     farmers fa
     ON fa.field = fr.fruit 
GROUP BY fr.fruit, fa.farmer;
```

Comment: Works as advertised, but sadly doesn't work for me. I really need the results as shown above with the null gaps if possible. And no matter whether farmers or sales have more entries, I need all the entries where fruit="apple" or whichever fruit.

Comment: @McRaef . . . I think a `LEFT JOIN` addresses the `NULL` issue.

Comment: I still need the results as shown above. I need a row for every row existing in the table with the most entries, where i do not know which will have the most entries. And     LEFT JOIN didn't work, neither did    RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

This will work for MySql 8.0:

```
with 
  farmers as (
    SELECT row_number() over ( order by null ) rn, farmer, field from farmers
    WHERE field = 'apple'
  ),    
  sales as (
    SELECT row_number() over ( order by null ) rn, fruit, amount from sales
    WHERE fruit = 'apple'
  )
select s.fruit, f.farmer, s.amount
from sales s left join farmers f
on f.rn = s.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o7juqDMBdwUauwgs6ebXfM/0)
Results:

```
| fruit | farmer | amount |
| ----- | ------ | ------ |
| apple | ben    | 50     |
| apple | joanna | 30     |
| apple | null   | 30     |
```

**Edit** for MySql 5.5:

```
select s.fruit, f.farmer, s.amount
from (
  select (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) AS rn, fruit, amount
  from sales, (select @row_number1:=0) t
  where sales.fruit = 'apple'
) s left join (
  select (@row_number2:=@row_number2 + 1) AS rn, farmer
  from farmers, (select @row_number2:=0) t
  where farmers.field = 'apple'
) f
on f.rn = s.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o7juqDMBdwUauwgs6ebXfM/2)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck to 5.7 for the moment. Nevertheless do I like your answer. And it would work for me in the future if I could do a full join on line 11, so that, when the tables farmer has more entries, i still get all the records from farmers, which I do not with your query if I look for "grapfruit" instead of apple

Comment: Same problem with the missing entry from farmers. But it doesn't matter anymore, I will use a different technique, since it seems that my approach isn't rational. Nevertheless, thanks a lot.